# How to allow only a certain range of numbers to be inputted into a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, input, range

I have this code where it will not allow multiple periods, and has to be passed into a double using valueIsGood to check if it is compatible. As well as not allow a empty string.

The method ReadNumberForHeight() does not allow a user to input any letters or special characters. Only numbers and the period(.) are allowed for input through this method.

I want to have a range for height since logically nobody can be .01 inches tall.
I want a range of only 3'0 and 12'5(3.0 and 12.5) as compatible input.
If it is not compatible go to the "So I am going to ask again..." if statement, and then go back to  ask the user again for their height.

An example input would be: 5.6, 5.11, 6.1

I have looked everywhere for a solution and have not found anything that has worked, or that I have tried that did work.

Any errors get caught by this loop but I still want a range of numbers from 3.0 to 12.5 as valid input to be accepted into this code.

```
string height1; 
bool valueIsGood;
double parsedValue;            
 do
 {
  Console.Write("What is your height?:");
  height1 = ReadNumberForHeight();
  valueIsGood = string.IsNullOrEmpty(height1) == false && double.TryParse(height1, out parsedValue);
     if (!valueIsGood)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("So I am going to ask again...\n");      
     }
  }
  while (!valueIsGood);
```

Here is the ReadNumberForHeight() method underneath.

```
private static string ReadNumberForHeight()
    {
        string input = "";
        do
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (char.IsNumber(keyInfo.KeyChar) || keyInfo.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                input = input + keyInfo.KeyChar;
                Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
            }
            
            if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                break;
            }
            if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
            
        } while (true);
        return input;
```

Comment: How in arithmetic or in general would you as a human determine if a number is within a range? if ```x``` is your input you would say: ```x >= MIN  && x <= MAX``` right? considering that its inclusive of MIN and MAX so somewhere you can check for ```if( x >= 3.0  && x <= 12.5) { ... }```

Comment: That has been the mind set toward this program. I have tried different ways but they seem to not work. That is why I am asking. I know an if statement could do that, yes, but I seem to not get it. Not the if statement but the implementing of this. I have tried many ways and they do not exactly run the way I intended.

Comment: *If you convert the number and try it that way, then it will give an error because of the possibility of two decimals like  ".." then an error occurs. I do not want this error.

Comment: I don't see any attempt in the code above to compare the value provided by the user with the lower and upper bounds you claim to want. **What have you tried?** What _specifically_ do you need help with here? What part of this goal is giving you trouble? Remember, to effectively solve a problem you don't know how to solve, just decompose the problem into smaller problems that you _do_ know how to solve.

Comment: When you convert the number into a decimal, there IS a possibility a input CAN BE ".." which are two periods. Inputted by accident or intentionally It will not pass into a double with this condition. A simple " x > 3 && x< 12.5" block of code will not work here. It ask for a height but I need help with the range part. This code is to be error proof. so even if I mess everything up by inputs it will work. I need it to check if it can pass into a double,  weather or not nothing is inside the string , and the part I am stuck on is it needs to be between a range of 3-12.5.

Comment: @JeremyW there is nothing wrong with the ```if``` statement or the condition. You want to ```error proof``` the application, then do it and validate the user input first! HINT: obviously entering two dots is clearly invalid input as well as numbers like 5.34.6 - a decimal number can only have a single dot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to read key by key?
You can just call `Console.ReadLine()` and then process the user input:

```
bool valueIsGood = false;
do {
    Console.Write("What is your height?:");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput) && double.TryParse(userInput, out double parsedValue)) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Good value! => {parsedValue}");
        valueIsGood = true;
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("So I am going to ask again...\n");
    }
} while (!valueIsGood);
Console.ReadKey();
```

This works as I understood you expected:

```
What is your height?:5d3
So I am going to ask again...

What is your height?:32.3
Good value! => 32.3
```

To accept only a range you can change the if condition to something like:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput) && double.TryParse(userInput, out double parsedValue) && parsedValue >= XXX && parsedValue <= YYYY)
```